# How does Firestore GRPC API handles resume token in multi-devices?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm coding a client which talks to Firestore via GRPC interface. I tried to understand how does the `listen` work. There, you first create a bi-direction channel by calling `Firestore.listen`. Then you feed it with `ListenRequest`. Each `ListenRequest` holds a so called `Target` which represents either a query or a list of documents you are interested in knowing their changes.

To be able to handle network connectivity issues, each `Target` has a `targetId`, which is simply a `int`. The server will stream messages to notify you that the `Target` with certain `targetId` is added on server side, and also it will return a so called `resumeToken`. So next time if your connection is broken, you can create a new bi-directional channel and add those `Target`s again, and you can also specify the `resumeToken` so that they will give you the correct states before your connection broken.

But I don't understand how do they handle the case that a user has multiple devices. Say on device A, the user create a Target with targetId 1, thus get a resumeToken A. On device B, the user create another Target (different query) and assign it also with targetId 1, thus get another resumeToken B. Now say device A reconnected, and feed targetId 1 and resumeToken A, will it confuse the Firestore server? because there are two Targets on the server with same targetId 1, but they belongs to two different query, will the Firestore server be clever enough to know that targetId 1 with resumeToken A belongs to query A?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the ["Manage User Sessions"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) to understand how Fireabase Authentication handles user sessions. Quoting from documentation:

> Every time a user signs in, the user credentials are sent to the
> Firebase Authentication backend and exchanged for a Firebase ID token
> (a JWT) and refresh token. Firebase ID tokens are short lived and last
> for an hour; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens.
> Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs:
>
> - The user is deleted.
> - The user is disabled.
> - A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like
>   password or email address updates.

***UPDATE:***

In order to solve the issue with the login from multiple devices, you may store the resume token generated for each device in a DB and send an opaque cookie that is only valid for the new device.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm talking about a different thing. In GRPC interface of Firestore, there is a `listen` function, you need provide that JWT to be able to establish the bi-direction GRPC channel, and then in that channel, you send target such as query. Query comes by first have some current snapshot then database deltas such as document modify and delete. In case the GRPC channel disconnected, they introduced a "resume token", so next time, you send the target and resume token, they will continue from where it stopped. The problem is now target id is just a simple int

Comment: and this int target id is decided by client, and my question is how does the Firestore server side distinct if the same target id belongs to same client or different clients

Comment: I understand now that you are asking how Firestore handles changes made by the same user who is logged in, in two different devices. Once the user is authenticated, your application uses his credentials in order to make calls to the API. [More information click](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#authentication_flow). So from both devices the user is listening to the same changes.